# How to duplicate an image file?

Tags: c, image, file

I use the following code in order to duplicate a text file: 
'oldfile' is the name of the file I want to duplicate, and 'newfile' is the name of the file I want to create.

```
void duplicate_file(char* oldfile, char* newfile) {
    char c;
    FILE* old = fopen(oldfile, "r");
    FILE* new = fopen (newfile, "w");

    while(1) {
        c=fgetc(old);
        if (c==EOF) {
            break;
        }
        fputc(c, new);
    }
}
```

However, once I try to duplicate an image file, the "new file" I get is not even an image. I think that a file consists of a list of bytes, so it doesn't matter whether the file is a text file or an image file, this function should work for all types of files. What am I missing?

Comment: just google "c how to copy binary file"

Comment: Change the type of `c` to `int`.

Comment: It works like a magic!
But, there is something that I don't understand. fgetc takes ONE character. So... why storing this char in a variable of size char causes problems? Why do we have to store it in a variable of size int?